# JQuery Animate callback function not working

Tags: jquery, css, callback, jquery-animate

I cannot get the following callback function to work. The alert is never triggered. The initial animation is performed on '.carousel-images' however.

```
$('.carousel-images').animate({'left' : left_indent},{queue:false, duration:500},function(){
    alert("animate carousel");

    //get the first list item and put it after the last list item   
    $('.carousel-images li:last').after($('.carousel-images li:first'));  

    //get the left indent to the default  
    $('.carousel-images').css({'left' : '-1200px'});  
});
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the [second method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) the complete callback has to be passes as a property to the options object

You need to use

```
$('.carousel-images').animate({'left' : left_indent},{queue:false, duration:500, complete: function(){
    alert("animate carousel");

    //get the first list item and put it after the last list item   
    $('.carousel-images li:last').after($('.carousel-images li:first'));  

    //get the left indent to the default  
    $('.carousel-images').css({'left' : '-1200px'});  
}});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was referring to old documentation

Answer (score 0):

your syntex is wrong, it should be

```
$('.carousel-images').animate({'left' : left_indent},{queue:false, duration:500, complete: function () {
                ...
            }
        });
```